# Media Queries not working at all whatsoever

Tags: html, css, media

I am in despair. I am trying to make a website and make it mobile-friendly and responsive, however, I cannot seem to get any kind of media query to work at all! All my sizes, width and heights are in "%/em" and my font-sizes are in "vw/em". The biggest problem I get is that, as the screen shrinks, so does my text, to the point where it simply becomes eye-straining to read! I don't see relevant to send any code but if need be, I shall send some of my code (my website is still offline and I cannot put it out there if this problem isn't fixed).

Here's what I have tried:

I have tried putting this in my  tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

No success when I try media query in a  tab or in a separate css stylesheet.

I have tried removing it aswell.

I have tried these media queries for my font-sizes:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    body { font-size: 60%;}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    body { 
        font-size: 80%;
        background-color: blue;  
    }

}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    body { font-size: 120%;}
}
```

I have also tried other media queries but absolutely NOTHING changes at all! Am I doing something wrong? Probably but what?!! This is leading to so many problems! I cannot change my header according to different screen sizes, I cannot change my display, my header links are a mess, etc.

Also, please note that I am a beginner and I do not use any javascript, bootstrap or whatever.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are a little weird. Perhaps with some logical constrains you can achieve what you are looking for? This is what I mean:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    body{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px){
    body { 
        background-color: blue;  
    }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1100px) {
    body { 
        background-color: purple;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1101px){
    body{
        background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

In my humble opinion, setting the intervals using both `min-width` and `max-width` help me visualize what's going on better. This [pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/eNJovg) shows the colors changing whenever you change the width. It doesn't do much good, but it's something to get started with media queries.

**EDIT:**

Pen contains transitions between colors because cool

Comment: This is weird, I have also previously tried the method you proposed but it did not work back then...now it does. It may have been because I was adding "screen" in the media query...? Anyway, thank you, it works wonders now! I still have so many problems to fix but I think I'll ask another question =D ! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you had some syntax problem, who knows... Adding screen should'n alter anything to the point everything stops working.

Comment: Thought so as well, it just didn't make sense. I discovered that when I tried putting my media query script in my head tag instead of inside my css stylesheet, it worked...I think that might have been my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's better to use media queries based on minimum screen width. Here is an working example with the code you posted:

Codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNJXXp

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    p { font-size: 60%;}
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
    p { 
        font-size: 80%;
        background-color: blue;  
    }

}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    p { font-size: 120%;}
}
```

Comment: Oh I just now understand what you meant by "min-width"! I had tried it before but I think I had the wrong syntax. Thank you! The other answer was a bit more precise because I like having an actual example of code but thank you for your help. =)